# Possible applications of Mean value theorem

Tags: real-analysis

> I would like to discuss the following two problems:
>
> 1) Let $f$ be a differentiable function on $[a,b]$ such that $f \neq 0$ , prove there exists $c \in (a,b)$ such that $$\frac{f'(c)}{f(c)}= \dfrac{1}{ a-c}+\frac{1}{b-c}$$
>   2) Suppose $f$ is a differentiable function on $[a,c]$ such that $\int^b_a f(x) \,dx= \int^c_b f(x)=0$ for some $b \in (a,c)$ show that there exists a $\xi \in (a,c)$ such that $f^\prime (\xi)=0$

I tried to construct some function $g$ which would satisfy MVT, but, I'm not able to guess the proper function. Prob 1) should probably include some logarithmic or exponential function.

Comment: For $(1)$ consider $g(x) = f(x) (a-x) (b-x) $ for the second problem let $g(x) =\int_{x} ^{b} f(t) \, dt$.

Comment: THanks , got it :)